# simple echo function does not spit out number

Tags: php

Below is my pretty simple attempt at trying to count the number of times $name string occurs in the $related_company string row of a table.

I was hoping it would spit out a number, but when i upload it to my webserver, it doesnt spit out anything.

Any ideas?

```
<?php

$db = new SQLite3('database.sqlite3');
$red = $db->query('SELECT * FROM news');

$name = strtolower("Tesla");
$related_company = $red->fetchArray($row['related_company']);


while ($row = $red->fetchArray()) { 
if (in_array($name, $related_company)){
$count+1;
}}
echo $count;

?>
```

Comment: Based on this code, you probably never enter your `if` condition because where you define `$related_company` you're using the (at that point) undefined variable `$row`.

Comment: You don't initialise `$count` and you don't increment it either therefore `$count === null` if you `var_dump($count)` at the end of your code. I would imagine that `echo $count;` throws a `Notice` if you had error reporting enabled. FYI `$count+1` does literally nothing; you want `$count++` or `$count += 1` or `$count = $count + 1`

Comment: The argument to `fetchArray()` is supposed to be a constant like `SQLITE3_ASSOC` or `SQLITE3_NUM`. Why are you passing `$row['related_company']`?

Comment: Ok, so I put $related_company inside the while loop. I want the related company to be a new company for each whileloop. I am checking how many times a company appears in a long table of news stories.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in a single query, without having to loop through the results. SQL has a `LIKE` operator to perform pattern matching in columns.

```
$db = new SQLite3('database.sqlite3');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM news WHERE related_company LIKE :name");
$name = '%' . strtolower("Tesla") . '%';
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
$count = $row['count'];
echo $count;
```

If the name comes from another table, you can join the tables.

```
$result = $db->query("
    SELECT c.name, COUNT(*) as count
    FROM Companies AS c
    JOIN news AS n ON n.related_company LIKE '%' || LOWER(c.name) || '%'");
while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    echo "{$row['name']}: {$row['count']}<br>";
}
```

Comment: The issue here would be that $name is a row from a different table (table named Companies) than $related_company. (from the table News)... So Im trying to do the logic in php instead of sql

Comment: You can use the `LIKE` operator in the `ON` condition of `JOIN`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried replicating your solution but it throws this error to this line:
$row = $stmt->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);


Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method SQLite3Stmt::fetchArray() in

Comment: Did you see my edit? I changed `$db->prepare` to `$db->query`